# Google places api should return only address

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use this url to get addresses with Get request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Nov&key=MyKet&types=address

But sometimes I get only streets without houses, sometimes I get even cities (if input=Minsk in Russian:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%A1%D0%9A&key=MyKey&types=address)

But I want to get only streets with houses, because I'm writing taxi application and I need there only full address, it's not enough if user selected only street.

So if I get from Google `Proletarsk street 25, Bern, Switzerland` - it's ok, but if I get from Google  `Proletarsk street, Bern, Switzerland` - it's not ok.

And when I get the responce from Google for streets and addresses it always return the same type

```
types =     (
        route,
        geocode
    );
```

So I can't even differ if the return value is a street or if it's a full address.

**Can you give me any advice?**

Comment: I think you are using wrong API Key.

Comment: No, I use my API Key, but I can't write it here, because it's not public. If I used wrong API Key, I wouldn't get any results. But I do get results, I just want to be sure that I get street with the house (not only the street)

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem in the meantime?

Comment: I just found a work around: I used the address, but I manually checked for the format after I get the returned values. So if user checked the row without home, I just said him that it's not the correct row. But you can manually filter results before showing them to user

Answer (score 2):

Based on the use case you describe, it sounds like you used the wrong API.

You should be using [the Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) if you have the address and would love Google Maps parse it for you and return extra information. You can determine if the result has a `street_number` so that you can tell if the result contains a full address. For example:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA)
would give you a result like this:

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4223455,
               "lng" : -122.0841893
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewp.....
```

Which give you a `street_number` and so you can tell it is a full address.

Comment: no, because if I get 5 results from google with streets and addresses, I can't check for all these 5 results with other requests